# Adding specified words to the begining of the mail title - Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to replace input box in this script into a combobox (select)? I need a mechanism that before sending an email shows a pop-up which allows to insert a specified text at the beginning of the mail title. Now I have a predefined text with possibility of changing it (input box) but I want to have a select option there instead - like choose text 1 or text 2. My code looks like that:

```
Public xFlag As Boolean
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim xText As String
On Error Resume Next
If xFlag = False Then
    xText = "My text: "
    If InStr(Item.Subject, xText) = False Then
L1:     xText = InputBox("Add to title", "Prefix", xText)
        If xText = "" Then
            xFlag = False
            Cancel = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Item.Subject = xText & "" & Item.Subject
        xFlag = True
        Cancel = True
    End If
Else
    xFlag = False
    xText = "My text:"
    If InStr(Item.Subject, xText) = False Then
      GoTo L1
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I am not into VBA at all, I've tried searching of some tutorials how to change this but it seems that none of them exists so I wanted to asked if it's even possible.

Comment: You have to look for *userform* and *listbox*. There should be enough tutorials around

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a userform with required controls on it, so you could easily display it instead of built-in dialog windows like input box. See [VBA UserForm sample: Select from a list of templates](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/vba-userform-sample-select-list-templates/) for more information.